# Sql - Consulta de dois valores máximos

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Suponhamos que temos essa base de dados

```
codigo, data, valor,seq
(1, '2014-01-01', 10,2),
(1, '2014-01-02', 20,1),
(2, '2014-01-03', 30,1),
(2, '2014-01-05', 40,1),
(2, '2014-01-05', 50,2),
(3, '2014-01-06', 60,1);
```

Eu quero pegar a data mais recente por cada código, no entanto, haverá datas repetidas, e quando isso ocorrer terei que pegar a maior Seq.

Ou seja, o resultado esperado é

```
1, '2014-01-02', 20,1
2, '2014-01-05', 50,2
3, '2014-01-06', 60,1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ba9e1/1/0

Comment: Mysql ou SqlServer?

Comment: @Sveen SqlServer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja o exemplo abaixo de como você poder fazer.

```
SELECT m.codigo, m.data,  m.valor,  m.seq 
FROM @minha_tabela m
join 
(
  SELECT m2.codigo, max(m2.data) as data, max(m2.seq) as seq
  FROM @minha_tabela m2
  group by m2.codigo
) m3 on m3.codigo = m.codigo
and m3.data = m.data
and m3.seq = m.seq
```

Answer (score 2):

Você só precisa verificar os registros que não possuam `data` ou `valor` maiores com o `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT m.*
  FROM minha_tabela m
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                    FROM minha_tabela m2
                   WHERE m2.codigo = m.codigo
                     AND (m2.data > m.data
                      OR m2.valor > m.valor)
                   GROUP BY m2.codigo,
                            m2.data,
                            m2.valor)
```

Comment: e se a data e o valor forem iguais para o mesmo código ? heheheh, faltou algo para a SEQ..

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza o `GROUP BY` resolve esse problema :D No exemplo que ele deixou no fiddle tem esse caso que você comentou

Comment: Tente alterar o valor para 40 na data (2, '2014-01-05', 50,2), e veja o que acontece :)

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza na verdade acho que esse `GROUP BY` tem que ser na  `query` de fora

Comment: @Sorack na sugestão apresentada acho que basta alterar "valor" por "seq", não?

Answer (score 1):

Mais uma suposição...

Para a data inicial eu tenho vários registros (leia-se sequências 1 a 10). Porém quero selecionar a maior data e dessa maior data a maior sequência.

Código para essa solução (pode ser útil para alguem):

```
SELECT m.codigo, m.data,  m.valor,  m.seq 
FROM minha_tabela m
where m.data = (select max(m2.data) from minha_tabela m2
                where m.codigo = m2.codigo)
and m.seq = (select max(m3.seq) from minha_tabela m3
             where m.codigo = m3.codigo
             and   m.data = m3.data);
```

Answer (score -1):

Parece-me que a solução mais simples para o problema é esta:

```
select codigo,MAX(valor)
from minha_tabela
group by codigo
```